# Horizontal and Vertical GridView with freeze header and column

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I have a little bit big GridView that I need to put it inside an area with width 960px. I have many columns in that GridView so I need it to be horizontally scrollable. I need to freeze the Header and to be scrollable and I need to freeze the first four columns, so how to do that?

I searched a lot in the Internet and I did not find anything related to what I want. I used some of the tutorials about freezing the header only but it did not work with me. Please help me.

Comment: I ask only about the css part because I don´t know about the rest: Do you need a container that has more than 4 columns, and you need the first 4 to always be positioned in the same place?

Comment: I am talking about GridView and I want to freeze the header and the first four columns

Answer (score 2):

There is a jQuery plugin that is called  [Freeze Header](http://brentmuir.com/projects/freezeheader/). You can check the demo and see if this is what you are looking for.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hi Aristotelis Kostopoulos, you are welcome. Glad I could help.